# Update DynamoDB item which contains stringset

Tags: java, database, amazon-dynamodb

I have table in **dynamoDB**, which has item contains partition(user_id) key and stringset(contacts).

**Example :**

```
Item: {user_id=7777777777, contacts=[2525252525-Kakadiya B, 9999999999-Hardik Kakadiya]}
```

I want to add one more contact into contacts and i also want to update one contact but how i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do that in Javascript SDK:

```
params = {};
params.TableName = "YourTable";
params.Key = {Key : "user_id"};
params.UpdateExpression = "ADD contacts :value";
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {":value": db.Set(["str1", "anotherStr"], 'S')};
db.updateItem(params);
```